# I Accidentally Pulled Master branch Of Repo1 Into local and changed Remote to Repo2 and pushed to specific Branch. How to Revert This?

Tags: git, push

I Had to -

1. Clone Branch 2 from of repo 1.
2. Change the Remote Origin of Local repo 2.
3. Push Code to branch 1 of repo 2.

I Did -

1. Clone Branch 1(master) from of repo 1.
2. Change the Remote Origin of Local repo 2.
3. Write Code.
4. Push Code to branch 1 of repo 2.

I don't care if my code loses, I just Want to Re-do This Process without any branch conflicts

Comment: This has nothing to do with Ruby on Rails

Comment: Redo your steps, and use force push to overwrite your branch in repo 2.

Answer (score 0):

Perform these steps

> 1. git log  // then copy the commit id at which the state of your branch is `correct`.
> 2. git reset --hard *commitId*
> 3. git push -f

In case you don't want to lose the code:

> 1. git log  // then copy the commit id at which the state of your branch is `correct`.
> 2. git reset --soft *commitId*
> 3. git reset .
> 4. git stash //saving the work
> 5. git reset --hard //Erase everything
> 6. git push -f

Now clone the correct repository and apply:
`git stash pop` //this will bring in the changes on the intended repository

solve if there are any merge conflicts.